# Как вывести на HTML страницу данные из API запросом на странице

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Вот код.

```
<script>
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://https://api-core.xxxxxxxxxx.com/api/articles/18782",
  "method": "GET"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);

  var content = response.number;
  $("#number").append(content);
  
  var content = response.fixedPlaces;
  $("#fixedPlaces").append(content);

});
</script>

<div id="number">ARTIKEL: </div>
<div id="fixedPlaces">FixPlatz: </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать так чтобы на HTML странице было поле для ввода которое бы меняло в конце ссылки **значения** при нажатии и уже потом ввыводило данные

```
...
    "url": "https://api-core.xxxxxxxxxx.com/api/articles/**знвчения**/",
...
```

Чтобы было примерно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]